# ERROR: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I have this error quite a bit in my code and I don't know how to fix it.
I have read many answers, but none of them solve it?

```dart
    if (event.snapshot.value["car_details"] != null) {
            setState(() {
              carDetailsDriver = event.snapshot.value["car_details"].toString();
            });
          }
          if (event.snapshot.value["driver_name"] != null) {
            setState(() {
              driverName = event.snapshot.value["driver_name"].toString();
            });
          }
          if (event.snapshot.value["driver_phone"] != null) {
            setState(() {
              driverphone = event.snapshot.value["driver_phone"].toString();
            });
          }

          if (event.snapshot.value["driver_location"] != null) {
            double driverLat = double.parse(
                event.snapshot.value["driver_location"]["latitude"].toString());
            double driverLng = double.parse(
                event.snapshot.value["driver_location"]["longitude"].toString());
            LatLng driverCurrentLocation = LatLng(driverLat, driverLng);
```

[image: click here to open the image with the error]

Comment: Check [important-concepts of null-safety](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts) it will explain everything

Comment: Could you add more code? Starting from the futureBuilder or StreamBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

By default the **snapshot's**  data type is `Object`. You can explicit it to be of dynamic type by doing this,

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) { // setting up data type of snapshot as just AsyncSnapshot.
  ...
```

Comment: Where should you specify this?

Comment: I asked you to provide more code but since you didn't provide I assumed you used `FutureBuilder()`. If you Are using `FutureBuilder()` then replace the builder line with the one I provided.

Comment: @CamiloRueda did u solve this ? I face the same issue. With firebase database v 9